# Change default Locale in angular

Tags: angular, internationalization, locale, angular8

I built an angular app in french, so now i want to use internationalization (i18n) to provide it in other languages like En, so the problem is the default locale for Angular is en-US and when i write this `<span i18n>Mes endroits</span>`,I have this

```
<file source-language= "en-US" datatype="plaintext" original="ng2.template">// source is English
    <body>
      <trans-unit id="4df6e2173dc9d9f8c60481273cf3371981e60fde" datatype="html">
        <source>Mes endroits</source> ... // but this is in french
```

and i want the source language to be **fr** and provide for example **messages.en.xlf**

> so can I change the default locale to fr , or I have to rewrite my code in English and provide  **messages.fr.xlf**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could help you [ngx-translate/ng2-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#5-use-the-service-the-pipe-or-the-directive), this library is very common in angular projects.

Personaly I prefer to do translation this way.

You will be able to use the translate pipe. like this

```
<p>{{ 'myPlaces' | translate }}</p>
```

And in a fr.json define :

```
{ 'myPlaces' : 'Mes endroits' }
```

I let you check the documentation

Answer (score 7):

This should be possible by setting the `sourceLocale` in the `angular.json` file. In my case the core application is german, so the relevant part of the file reads as follows:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "angular-client": {
      "i18n": {
        "sourceLocale": {
          "code": "de",
          "baseHref": ""
        },
        "locales": {
          "en": {
            "translation": "src/locale/messages.en.xlf",
            "baseHref": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For me this works just as expected, the XLF files are all attributed correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the documentation provided by angular.

Stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-datepicker?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

In app.module.ts add this in providers:

```js
{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'de-DE'}
```

Comment: I tried that it only provide fr locale but don't change the default one

Comment: Also you can try with  { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'de-DE'} in app.module.ts